# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Nom' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular8

I am getting this error message  when i wanna add a new line in my table:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Nom' of undefined
  at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (MedecinsComponent.html:43)
  at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:36043)
  at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35055)
  at callViewAction (core.js:35421)
  at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:35378)
  at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35056)
  at callViewAction (core.js:35421)
  at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:35349)
  at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35062)
  at callViewAction (core.js:35421)
```

Here's my code:

**component.ts**

```js
this.cols = [
  { field: 'User.Nom', header: 'Nom' },
  { field: 'User.Prénom', header: 'Prénom' },
  { field: 'User.Tel', header: 'Téléphone' },
  { field: 'User.Email', header: 'Email' },
  { field: 'User.Pays', header: 'Pays' },
  { field: 'User.Login', header: 'Login' },
  { field: 'User.Password', header: 'Password' },
  { field: 'User.Active', header: 'Active' },
  { field: 'Details', header: 'Détails'}
];
```

**component.html**

```html
<p-dialog header="Détails de l'utilisateur" [(visible)]="displayDialog" [responsive]="true" showEffect="fade" [modal]="true" [closable]="true" [width]="600">
    <div class="ui-g ui-fluid" *ngIf="medecin">              
        <div class="ui-g-4"><label for="Nom">Nom</label></div>
        <div class="ui-g-8"><input pInputText id="Nom" [(ngModel)]="medecin.Users.Nom"/></div>
    </div>
</p-dialog>
```

**model.ts**

```js
import { User } from './user';

export class Medecin {
  Id: number;
  Users_Id: number;
  Image: ByteLengthChunk;
  Details: string;
  Updated: Date;
  Created: Date;
  Deleted: Date;
  Users: User;
}
```

So, is there an implementation issue? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: `Users` isn't defined in `medecin`

Comment: Please share your component code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize and get the value of "User" instance first.
so before writing "this.col = ..."
try getting the user instance & then pass-on the user properties to "col" array of objects.

Comment: :) Pleasure is all mine

Answer (score 0):

Since it says "can't find property Nom in undefined", it looks like you have no object `User` to start with.